# How to prevent setting saved username and password values to textfield and password field in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I'm using PHP, HTML, JavaScript, etc. for my website. Now the scenario is I've a login form which has two fields `Username(input type="text") and Password(input type="password")`. When the page loads for the first time and I enter the username and password values the browser asks for Remember Password option.

I clicked on Remember Password.Then the login form gets close and first page after login is opened. Till now everything works fine.

**Issue :**

- I'm facing is in New User Registration form which I can access after logging in. This User Registration form has three fields viz. `Username(input type="text"), Password(input type="password") and Email(input type="email")`.
- When I click on a hyperlink for User Registration form the web page containing User Registration form loads but it loads with two fields filled with values. The Username field contains the username I entered while logging in and the Password field contains the password I entered while logging in. At the time of login I've set the Remember Password option in browser.

I'm having this problem in Google Chrome. In Mozilla Firefox it's working fine. No more filled fields are there when the USer Registration form page loads.

Comment: This is a setting in Google Chrome called Autofill, maybe changing the values of what you call the inputs? Google sees that they are named password and username and auto-fills them in

Comment: @Chitowns24:I tried your trick but it's not working.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't tested it out it was just a theory. What did you rename them to just curious?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: @Chitowns24:yeah, that's what exactly I was looking for. Thanks for the research you do on my behalf.

Comment: No problem! I actually am implementing this on my system as we speak now as well